# How to invalidate layout on bounds change

Tags: ios

I need to invalidate the layout of my collection view on rotation of my device. Someone told me that I need to use:

```
invalidateLayout(with: invalidationContext(forBoundsChange: .zero))
```

inside:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

}
```

But I'm not sure how to use that in relation to my `collectionView`.

Comment: use collectionView.invalidateLayout().
This method invalidates the current layout and triggers a layout update.

Comment: That gives me `Value of type 'UICollectionView' has no member 'invalidateLayout'`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
override public func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

        collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }
```

This method is overridden within the UIView that hosts the collectionView